# Ansible known_hosts task fails

Tags: ansible

I'm new with ansible and I created small ansible-playbook, that adds github ssh host key to known_hosts in each server:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: Add github to ssh known-hosts
    known_hosts:
     name: "TS_github"
     key: "github.com,192.30.252.129 ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAq2A7hRGmdnm9tUDbO9IDSwBK6TbQa+PXYPCPy6rbTrTtw7PHkccKrpp0yVhp5HdEIcKr6pLlVDBfOLX9QUsyCOV0wzfjIJNlGEYsdlLJizHhbn2mUjvSAHQqZETYP81eFzLQNnPHt4EVVUh7VfDESU84KezmD5QlWpXLmvU31/yMf+Se8xhHTvKSCZIFImWwoG6mbUoWf9nzpIoaSjB+weqqUUmpaaasXVal72J+UX2B+2RPW3RcT0eOzQgqlJL3RKrTJvdsjE3JEAvGq3lGHSZXy28G3skua2SmVi/w4yCE6gbODqnTWlg7+wC604ydGXA8VJiS5ap43JXiUFFAaQ=="
```

But, for some reasons, this playbook fails for every host with error:

```
fatal: [clusterapp-1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/ssh-keygen -F TS_github -f /tmp/tmpgROT5p", "failed": true, "msg": "", "rc": 1, "stderr": "", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

For some reasons it uses `/tmp/tmpgROT5p` as a keyfile, which is false for obvious reasons. As stated in [ansible doc](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/known_hosts_module.html) known_hosts module should use     "(homedir)+/.ssh/known_hosts", but it doesn't happened.

I start playbook as follows:

```
 ansible-playbook -i hosts github_keys.yml
```

I also tried to start playbook with -vvv key, but I didn't get any useful information.

My ansible.cfg file:

```
[defaults]
transport=ssh
host_key_checking=false
```

Comment: "For some reasons it uses /tmp/tmpgROT5p as a keyfile, which is false for obvious reasons." I don't think the reasons are obvious. Ansible likely saves the key to a temporary file during the execution of the task. Is your `/tmp` writeable?

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes, it is writeable. But I think that ssh-keygen expect that /tmp/tmpgROT5p already exist, because I run this command manually `/usr/bin/ssh-keygen -F TS_github -f /tmp/tmpgROT5p` and have the following output: `ssh-keygen: /tmp/tmpgROT5p: No such file or directory`

Comment: Ansible is almost certainly **creating** that file in `/tmp/` before running `ssh-keygen`. Try creating the file with the contents of the public key and run the command manually - see if it works or errors out.

Comment: @ceejayoz ok, I copied my know_hosts file to /tmp: `cp ~/.ssh/known_hosts /tmp/tmpgROT5p` and run ssh-keygen command and it finished without errors. I still can not realise why ansible create new file and don't use existing known_hosts file

Comment: It creates a temporary file for the SSH public key, not the `known_hosts` file.

Comment: I think your problem may be the `github.com,192.30.252.129 ` bit at the beginning of your key. http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/known_hosts_module.html says `key` should be **just** the key. The `github.com` bit should go in the `name` argument instead.

Comment: @ceejayoz not exact, but you gave me right direction for answer: `name` should be `github.com` and `key` should be `github.com,192.30.252.129 ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAA...` And then everything works perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The `name` should be the name of the host.

So in your case, the name needs to be `github.com` and `key` should be `github.com,192.30.252.129 ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAA...`

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: Add github to ssh known-hosts
    known_hosts:
     name: github.com
     key: "github.com,192.30.252.129 ssh-rsa AAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAq2A7hRGmdnm9tUDbO9IDSwBK6TbQa+PXYPCPy6rbTrTtw7PHkccKrpp0yVhp5HdEIcKr6pLlVDBfOLX9QUsyCOV0wzfjIJNlGEYsdlLJizHhbn2mUjvSAHQqZETYP81eFzLQNnPHt4EVVUh7VfDESU84KezmD5QlWpXLmvU31/yMf+Se8xhHTvKSCZIFImWwoG6mbUoWf9nzpIoaSjB+weqqUUmpaaasXVal72J+UX2B+2RPW3RcT0eOzQgqlJL3RKrTJvdsjE3JEAvGq3lGHSZXy28G3skua2SmVi/w4yCE6gbODqnTWlg7+wC604ydGXA8VJiS5ap43JXiUFFAaQ=="
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can use a .ssh/config file for the specific user to ignore the known_hosts if you are just trying to avoid being prompted and this falls withing your security requirements.

Host *
    StrictHostKeyChecking no

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround could be to use blockinfile.

```
  - name: Add github to ssh known-hosts
    blockinfile:
      path: ~/.ssh/known_hosts
      block: "github.com,192.30.252.129 ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAq2A7hRGmdnm9tUDbO9IDSwBK6TbQa+PXYPCPy6rbTrTtw7PHkccKrpp0yVhp5HdEIcKr6pLlVDBfOLX9QUsyCOV0wzfjIJNlGEYsdlLJizHhbn2mUjvSAHQqZETYP81eFzLQNnPHt4EVVUh7VfDESU84KezmD5QlWpXLmvU31/yMf+Se8xhHTvKSCZIFImWwoG6mbUoWf9nzpIoaSjB+weqqUUmpaaasXVal72J+UX2B+2RPW3RcT0eOzQgqlJL3RKrTJvdsjE3JEAvGq3lGHSZXy28G3skua2SmVi/w4yCE6gbODqnTWlg7+wC604ydGXA8VJiS5ap43JXiUFFAaQ=="
      marker: "# {mark} github"
```

Sure, using known_hosts is the recommended way to go, but this one is working quite well. Also suitable for managing /etc/hosts